# Can't get value from custom attribute android

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas, android-custom-view

Why always default value?

```
    private fun setupAttributes(attrs: AttributeSet?) {
        val typedArray = context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomView,
                0, 0)
        mColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.CustomView_secondHandColor, Color.CYAN)
        paint.color = mColor
    }
```

Comment: Have you passed that attribute correctly from your view xml?

Comment: Can you help to update your question to attach your implementation code of how you call the `secondHandColor`?